# How can I detect that system has webcam plugin installed or not using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webcam

In my app, I am using webcam functionality. But if user doesn't have webcam plugin installed in his system then I want to prompt a message to him.

There are 2 things:

1. webcam plugin is not installed
2. webcam plugin is installed, but webcam is not present.

So I want the first condition code in JavaScript

EDIT

I am using this code for finding whether webcam is present or not

```
$('#cambg').webcam({
    width : 320,
    height : 240,
    mode : 'callback',
    swffile : '/flash/libraries/jquery/webcam/jscam_canvas_only.swf',

    onLoad : function() {
      var cams = webcam.getCameraList();

      if (cams.length) {
        // success
      }
       else {
        // error                            
      }
    }
});
```

Please help me to find this solution.

Comment: Please post some relevant code of what you have tried.  We'll help you fix what doesn't work, but we will not build it for you.

Comment: Which plugin are you using to communicate with the webcam?

Comment: @sys.stderr webcam.js

Comment: @Rishi link to webcam.js?

Comment: @FireCrakcer37 I have updated my code which I am using for finding webcam. but I am not getting how to find whether webcam plugin is installed or not ? just give some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [Webcam](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) jquery plugin.

In particular, the `debug` option:

```
$("#camera").webcam({
    width: 320,
    // other options etc.
    debug: function(type, message) { 
        if (message === "Camera started") { window.webcam.started = true; } 
    }
});
```

Another option is to take a look at ScriptCam, in particular, it's error handling:
[scriptCam](http://www.scriptcam.com/docs.cfm)

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between OnLoad and debug option ?