# How can I check if user has a webcam or not?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, webcam

I need to know if there's a way to know if the user has a webcam on his computer using javascript or maybe php.

Comment: PHP won't tell you if the user has a webcam as PHP runs server side and therefore isn't able to see the clients hardware.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728055/how-can-i-detect-that-system-has-webcam-plugin-installed-or-not-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin:

> http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

```
if(webcam.getCameraList().length == 0){  
   alert('You don\'t have a web camera');  
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the guide, but some details was missing, só I will reply here with the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20641960/2097633

Answer (score 11):

```
if(confirm('Do you have a webcam?')) {
    //they said yes :-)
} else {
    //they said no :-(
}
```

Comment: Way to go to check webcam :)

Comment: That's terrible, but +1 for making me laugh.

Comment: easiest way possible...let the user be your "computer" :)

Comment: smart trick but not effective if users are bit evil...

Answer (score 0):

Muhammet was right. First need to add the plugin http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/
Then you'll need to start the plugin:

```
$("#camera").webcam({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            mode: "callback",
            swffile: "/lorran/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
            onTick: function() {},
            onSave: function() {},
            onCapture: function() {},
            debug: function() {},
            onLoad: function() {}
        });
```

Then you add the script that check if user has a webcam.

```
var test;
        test = function(){
            var tester = false;
            try{
                if(webcam.getCameraList().length == 0){  
                   alert('You dont have a camera');  
                                            return;
                }else{
                    alert("cam");
                                            return;

                }
                tester = true;
            }catch(e){
                tester = false;
                setTimeout(test,1000);
            }
        }
        setTimeout(test,1000);
```

This try and catch is needed for the flash that have a delay to start, so you need to keep trying till the method webcam.getCameraList() exist.

Comment: what is the purpose of checking web camera over and over

Comment: Not over and over, just until the flash loads... if you use it just in `$(document).ready` will return a erro telling that getCameraList isnt defined.

Comment: And i also putted 'return' when get the answer.