# Check if user has webcam or not using JavaScript only?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to figure out whether a user has a webcam or not using only JavaScript? I don't want to use any plugin for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641213/how-can-i-check-if-user-has-a-webcam-or-not

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I dont want to use any plugin dear. I want to check using javacript only.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Not true. :) See my answer.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak HTML5 meaning the additions to JS. Notice that i don't use any HTML code, just JS.

Comment: @gtournie's answer should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use a new HTML5 API to check if they give you permission to use the webcam. After all, if they deny permission, they might as well not have a webcam, from the code's perspective.

See [`navigator.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator.getUserMedia).

EDIT:

```
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia || // use the proper vendor prefix
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

navigator.getMedia({video: true}, function() {
  // webcam is available
}, function() {
  // webcam is not available
});
```

Comment: getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins for more details.

Answer (score 43):

You don't necessarily need to get the permission to know if the user has a webcam, you can check it with `enumerateDevices`:

```
function detectWebcam(callback) {
  let md = navigator.mediaDevices;
  if (!md || !md.enumerateDevices) return callback(false);
  md.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {
    callback(devices.some(device => 'videoinput' === device.kind));
  })
}

detectWebcam(function(hasWebcam) {
  console.log('Webcam: ' + (hasWebcam ? 'yes' : 'no'));
})
```

Comment: Can you provide the solution without using the callback?

Comment: @Avatar I don't see the point. The callback gives you the info, if you don't use it you won't know if the user has a webcam or not...

Answer (score 4):

You can check if the user has a webcam using this plugin: http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/

```
if(webcam.getCameraList().length == 0){  
   alert('You don\'t have a web camera');  
}
```

Taken from here: [How can I check if user has a webcam or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641213/how-can-i-check-if-user-has-a-webcam-or-not)

**Edit**: I see you updated your question to say that you don't want to use a plugin. In this case, you could try using the `getUserMedia` API:

```
function success(stream){
  // The success function receives an argument which points to the webcam stream
  document.getElementById('myVideo').src = stream; 
}

function error(){
  alert("No webcam for you, matey!");
}

if (navigator.getUserMedia) { 
   navigator.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:false}, success, error);
} else { 
   error();
}
```

Source: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/06/html5/filtering-a-webcam-using-getusermedia-and-html5-canvas

Answer (score 1):

There is NO way you can read current browser settings.
the only thing we can do is try to access the webcam/microphone and see if we are able to access that device like...

```
navigator.getMedia({video: true}, function() {
  // webcam is available
}, function() {
  // webcam is not available
});
```

BUT **** One important thing to note here, if you follow this approach then be aware that ....

Also please note that, you have to use HTTPS to use webcam/microphone and it will prompt you the browser specific permission popup with allow and block buttons ONLY ONCE, you will **NOT** see this permission popup again as HTTPS save the permission.

The only way to get this permission popup again is to:

1. Clear your cache and
2. Reset the browser settings
3. Open a new instance of the browser.

FYI ... You cannot manipulate browser specific setting using JavaScript
So don't event go that way, unless you have time to kill

Comment: Not true at all. See @gtournie's answer how it can be done.

Comment: Actually, Navigator.getUserMedia() is deprecated, advised to use MediaDevices.getUserMedia()

Answer (score 1):

`Navigator.getUserMedia()` is being depreciated as of 2019. To access webcam, use [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) instead.

Note that `navigator.mediaDevices` will return `undefined` if the current document isn't loaded securely. URLs served from `localhost` are usually OK.

Sample code to test for and access webcam:

```
const constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: { width: 1280, height: 720 },
};
if (!navigator.mediaDevices) {
    console.log("Document not secure. Unable to capture WebCam.");
} else {
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function(stream) {
            //show webcam stream
            let videoIn = document.createElement("video");
            videoIn.autoplay = true;
            document.body.appendChild(videoIn);
            videoIn.srcObject = stream;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Unable to capture WebCam.", err);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While here, and inspired by other answers, as part of an implementation I'm working on I am using the following function to return a boolean checking for an active stream.

The project is a little old, hence jQuery and ES5, though hope this can prove useful to someone:

```
function() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(VIDEO_CONSTRAINTS)
    .then(function(stream) { deferred.resolve(stream.active); })
    .catch(function() { deferred.resolve(false) })

  return deferred.promise()
}
```

This can then be used as follows:

```
checkStreamActive()
  .then(function(activeStream) {
    if(activeStream) {
      // do something
    } else {
    // do something else
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async function detectWebcam() {
    try {

        var md = navigator.mediaDevices;
        var results = false;

        if (!md || !md.enumerateDevices) results = false;

        const devices = await md.enumerateDevices();
        results = devices.some(device => 'videoinput' === device.kind);

        return results;

    } catch (error) { return false; }
}
```

Comment: Please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.

Answer (score -1):

**strong text**Try this code to check whether the device has webcam or not by javascript alert[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32YCX.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            webcam_check_func();
        });

        function webcam_check_func() {
            var hasWebcam = false;
            var device = [];
            if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
                
                navigator.enumerateDevices = function (callback) {
                    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(callback);
                };
                navigator.enumerateDevices(function (devices) {
                    devices.forEach(function (my_device) {

                        if (my_device.kind === 'videoinput') {
                            debugger;
                            hasWebcam = true;
                        }
                    }
                    );
                    alert("Has Web Camera -->" + hasWebcam);
                });
            }

        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).