# javascript getting picture from video camera to canvas

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, camera, html5-video

After being searching in google and here. I can't figure out how to get a picture from my video camera. My web app has a canvas and a camera button where the user clicks and open a video screen with a button ready to shot and keep a picture on the canvas.
The videocamera Works preatty fine. Here is the code:

```
$("#camara").on("click",function(){     
    var constraints={ video: true };
    var video = $("#video")[0];     
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function(stream) {            
          var videoTracks = stream.getVideoTracks();
          console.log('Got stream with constraints:', constraints);
          console.log('Using video device: ' + videoTracks[0].label);
          stream.onended = function() {
            console.log('Stream ended');
          };
          window.stream = stream; // make variable available to browser console
          video.srcObject = stream;
        }).catch(function(error) {
              if (error.name === 'ConstraintNotSatisfiedError') {
                errorMsg('The resolution ' + constraints.video.width.exact + 'x' +
                    constraints.video.width.exact + ' px is not supported by your device.');
              } else if (error.name === 'PermissionDeniedError') {
                errorMsg('Permissions have not been granted to use your camera and ' +
                  'microphone, you need to allow the page access to your devices in ' +
                  'order for the demo to work.');
              }
              errorMsg('getUserMedia error: ' + error.name, error);
});
```

The code above Works fine. The problem comes when I shot the camera and I try to keep the picture on canvas. This is the code I am using:

```
$("#snap").on("click", function(){
        var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
        var video=$("#video")[0];
        ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        });
```

The variable canvas is a global variable which I also use for others porpuses. The problem here is that I don't know how to get a picture from the video camera. I have also tried to use an Image Object and load the picture in the src attribute, but it didn't work either. 
Any idea would be grateful.

Comment: Did you call video.play() anywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I capture an image via the user's webcam using getUserMedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975431/how-can-i-capture-an-image-via-the-users-webcam-using-getusermedia)