# Is it possible to embed webcam video into browswer screen capture?

Tags: html, web, screen-capture, webapi

I am thinking to use [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture) to record sessions on my screen. But I also want to have my webcam video being displayed at the bottom right of my screen. Like this one:

[image]

Is it possible? If so, how can I embed the webcam video to the screen recording? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975431/how-can-i-capture-an-image-via-the-users-webcam-using-getusermedia

Have you tried this?

Comment: @lost_in_magento thanks! but that is for ```getUserMedia```, right? Here I want to capture the screen by using ```getDisplayMedia```, and embed the webcam video to the captured screen, any ideas?