# Can I transfer the value received with getUserMedia to the input file?

Tags: file, input, upload, getusermedia

I have a html5 web application running under webview.

I want to send data with form enctype multipart/form-data by taking photo from user's camera.

I tried something in input type file but unfortunately when I press "Select File" in all of them, it opens camera and file selection list.

```
<form action="/upload.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" id="cameraPic" accept="image/*;capture=camera" /><br>
    <input type="file" id="cameraPic" capture="environment" accept="image/*"/><br>
    <input type="file" id="cameraPic" capture="user" accept="image/*"/><br>
    <input type="file" id="cameraPic" name="profile_pic" accept=".jpg, .jpeg"/><br>

  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So I wanted to try to capture and upload the camera with "mediaDevices.getUserMedia".

With the code below, I can take a photo and see it on the page. But how can I send the image from the page to the backend?

- Assignment of input file value (I don't think it will be for security reasons)
- Find Base64 code and upload it to Textarea and send it.
- Putting "Upload" button next to "Take Photo" button.

I am undecided about what to do and how to do it?

I don't know if my path is correct or not.

Another problem is "getUserMedia" back camera not opening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Take Photo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    html,body,video {margin:0;padding:0;}
    button {height:3em;width:10em;left:0;top:0;position:fixed;}
    video {height:3em;width:10em;right:0;top:0;position:fixed;}
    #takePhotoCanvas {width:100vw;height:100vh;left:0;top:3em;position:fixed;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="takePhotoButton()">Take Photo</button>
<video autoplay=""></video>
<canvas id="takePhotoCanvas"></canvas>



<script>
var imageCapture;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
.then(mediaStream => {
document.querySelector('video').srcObject = mediaStream;

const track = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
imageCapture = new ImageCapture(track);
})
.catch(error => console.log(error));


function grabFrameButton() {
  imageCapture.grabFrame()
  .then(imageBitmap => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#grabFrameCanvas');
    drawCanvas(canvas, imageBitmap);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};

function takePhotoButton() {
  imageCapture.takePhoto()
  .then(blob => createImageBitmap(blob))
  .then(imageBitmap => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#takePhotoCanvas');
    drawCanvas(canvas, imageBitmap);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};

/* Utils */

function drawCanvas(canvas, img) {
  canvas.width = getComputedStyle(canvas).width.split('px')[0];
  canvas.height = getComputedStyle(canvas).height.split('px')[0];
  let ratio  = Math.min(canvas.width / img.width, canvas.height / img.height);
  let x = (canvas.width - img.width * ratio) / 2;
  let y = (canvas.height - img.height * ratio) / 2;
  canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height,
      x, y, img.width * ratio, img.height * ratio);
};

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may find it helpful to look at these [WebRTC Samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/) . They show you some things about image capture and camera selection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I capture an image via the user's webcam using getUserMedia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975431/how-can-i-capture-an-image-via-the-users-webcam-using-getusermedia)

Comment: @O.Jones It does the capturing and transferring the canvas image in my code. But I need to post the image on the canvas to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos) is worthwhile.

It looks like you need [canvas.toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob).

Something like this might work.

```js
canvas.toBlob(function (blob){
   const fd = new FormData();
   fd.append('fname', 'pic.jpg');
   fd.append('data', blob);
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/uploadedendpoint ',
       data: fd,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false
    })
    .done(function(data) {
       console.log(data);
}, 'image/jpeg')
```

This uses the jquery ajax call to post the encoded jpeg picture from the canvas.

Not debugged ... that's up to you.