# Detect user webcam but use it later

Tags: javascript, webcam, detect

My problem is :  I just want to detect the webcam to know if I show the button "take a picture with your webcam" but i don't want to film the user if he doesn't click on this button. ( And I don't want to show the button if the webcam isn't available)

I succeed to get webcam stream but i have to use navigator.getUserMedia to know if the webcam is available and i have to use the same function to get the stream of the webcam so the user will be asked 2 times if he wants to share his webcam.

This is my code for detecting webcam :

```
errBack = function (error) {
    //We hide photo button if video is not supported
    document.getElementById("OpenWebcam").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    console.log("Video capture error: ", error.code);
};

// Put video listeners into place
if (navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
    navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
        // video.src = stream;
        //  video.play();
    }, errBack);
} else if (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
        //  video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
        //  video.play();
    }, errBack);
} else if (navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
    //  navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function (stream) {
        //  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        // video.play();
    }, errBack);
}
```

I use the same code to get the stream from the webcam (I just uncomment the line video.src and video.play)

The best for me is that i detect that there is a webcam (but i don't ask permission to the user) so i show the button and when the user clicks on the button the navigator ask him if he wants to share his webcam.

Do you know if the is a way of doing this?

Comment: You might want to check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288918/check-if-user-has-webcam-or-not-using-javascript-only)